# How to find out if a variable is signed or unsigned?

Tags: c, unsigned

In a C implementation that uses 2's complement integers, if an signed integer is negative, then the highest bit is `1`, otherwise `0`.

Lets take `char` and `unsigned char`, the range for a `signed char` is `-128` to `127` and `unsigned char` is `0` to `255`, but in fact their hexadecimal are in range of `0x00` to `0xff`.
My question is now if a `char` and `unsigned char` are stored in memory using 8 bits binary number, how does the computer itself know whether it is `signed` or `unsigned`?

```
char a = 0xff; printf("%d", a); //its result is -1.
unsigned char a = 0xff; printf("%d", a); //its result is 255.
```

In the example above, how does `printf` know the value of `0xff` is signed or unsigned? Is that only depends on the definition of `a`?

Comment: By the way, C doesn't distinguish between `0xff`, `0377` and `255`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many related questions here, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192688/warning-c4018-signed-unsigned-mismatch) one.

Your question is not quite right: for `signed` the highest bit is not always `1` -- only if the value is negative. In fact, `signed` or `unsigned` are "types" attributed to the exact same bit patters, and how these bit patterns are interpreted *when compared or promoted* is defined by their respective types.

For example:

```
unsigned char u = 0xFF; // decimal 255
signed char s = 0xFF; // decimal -1
```

You can see how both values are the same, in both the highest bit is set, but they differ in their types.

The compiler uses a [type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) to know how to interpret values, and it is the task of the programmer to assign meaningful types to values. In the above example, I told the compiler that the first `0xFF` should be interpreted as an `unsigned` value (see also the include file [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)) with the maximum range:

```
u = 0x00; // decimal 0, CHAR_MIN
u = 0xFF; // decimal 255, UCHAR_MAX
```

and the second `0xFF` as a `signed` value with the maximum range:

```
s = 0x00; // decimal 0, CHAR_MIN
s = 0x7F; // decimal 127, SCHAR_MAX
s = 0x80; // decimal -127, SCHAR_MIN (note how 0x7F + 1 = 0x80, decimal 127 + 1 = -127, called an overflow)
s = 0xFF; // decimal -1
```

For the printf in your example, the `%d` tells it to expect a `signed int` value. According to the [integer promotion rules of the C language](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) the smaller `char` type is either sign-extended (if it's `signed` type) or zero-extended (if it's `unsigned` type). To finish with the above example:

```
printf("%d", u); // passes a int 0x000000FF, decimal 128, to the function
printf("%d", s); // passes a int 0xFFFFFFFF, decimal -1, to the function
```

More printf formatting specifiers are [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), for example `%u` might be interesting for you in this context.

Answer (score 6):

On a `printf()` call (and other occasions), the integer promotion rules apply.

The compiler converts the given value into an `int`. This happens depending on the signedness of the char (which is, of course, known by the compiler). So depending on the signedness of the char, the compiler does the conversion by filling with `0` bits or with the highest bit of the char.

Answer (score 3):

> Lets take char and unsigned char, the range for a signed char is -128 to 127 and unsigned char is 0 to 255, but in fact their hexadecimal are in range of 0x00 to 0xff.

This statement is confusing and misleading. `0xFF` is just another way to write 255. You could just as well have said *'In hexadecimal the range for a signed char is `-0x80` to `0x7F` and for a signed char is `0x00` to `0xFF`.'*

> My question is now if a char and unsigned char are stored in memory using 8 bits binary number, how does the computer itself know whether it is signed or unsigned?

The computer doesn't know.  **You** tell it whether you want to interpret that memory as a signed number or unsigned number by typing the word `unsigned`.

> In the example above, how does printf know the value of 0xff is signed or unsigned?

Leave `printf` out of it. Let's make a simpler example:

```
char a = 128;
```

What happens?  128 is larger than the largest possible signed char (again, assuming 8 bit chars in twos complement).  So the value *wraps around to the smallest possible value*; this becomes -128.

```
char a = 129;
```

What happens? 129 is larger than the largest possible signed char by *two*. So it wraps around to the *second smallest possible value*, -127.

```
char a = 130;
```

This is *three* larger than the largest possible value, so it wraps around to *the third smallest possible value*, -126.

.... skip a few ...

```
char a = 255;
```

this is 128 larger than the largest possible value, so it wraps around to the 128th smallest possible value, which is -1.

Got it?

OK, now that we understand that:

```
char a = 255;
unsigned char b = 255;
```

Now what happens when we say

```
int c = a;
int d = b;
```

?  We have a signed integer. `a` we have already determined has wrapped around to -1, which is in the range of an integer, so `c` becomes the integer -1.  `b` is the unsigned char 255, which is in the range of an integer, so `d` becomes the integer `255`.

The fact that the in-memory contents of `a` and `b` are the same is irrelevant. That memory is *interpreted as a number* based on the *type* that you assigned to `a` and `b`. In particular, the conversion of that bit pattern to an integer bit pattern is entirely dependent on the type.

Comment: "0xFF is just another way to write 128." ??  Suggest rewriting.