# Reading 2 bytes in the correct way

Tags: c

I've a sensor that delivers its 16bits  in this way : 1. MSB 2. LSB  :

The values are in this range :

```
0xffff ===> -32767   MIN 
0x8000 ====> -1 LSB say -1 
0x0000 ====> +1 LSB say 1 
0x7FFF ====> 32767 MAX
```

I'm trying to display these values in a readable way. For that I've written this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(){
  char msbyte =0x7f;
  char lsbyte = 0xff;
  int16_t temp=0;
  temp = (msbyte<<8) | lsbyte;
  printf(" %4x temp %d ", temp,temp);

  return 0 ;

}
```

the result that I get is strange:

> ffffffff temp -1

I expected the output to be:

> 7fff temp 32767

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your data type `char` (which is signed) and format code `%d` (which is signed) define whether your values are interpreted as signed or unsigned integers. There is more detail on that in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497382/how-to-find-out-if-a-variable-is-signed-or-unsingned/22498104#22498104) answer.

Comment: Prefer `"%" PRId16` to print `int16_t`

Comment: `LSB` and `MSB` mean `least significant BIT` and `most significant BIT`, please dont invent your own language ...

Comment: Are you sure you even want a signed result?

Comment: @specializt - Although less common, `LSB` and `MSB` have certainly been used for byte rather than bit. Wikipedia agrees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit

Comment: [citation needed]. I have _never_ seen or even heard of such a use of this term - and im in the business for quite some time now. Im guessing its what the internet superheros nowadays _want_ it to be - but thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
uint8_t msbyte =0x7f;
uint8_t lsbyte = 0xff;
```

If `char` behaves as `signed char` on your implementation, lsbyte while oring would extend the sign bit and result may be unexpected. To solve the problem you should use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/fx9Bgy)

Although this way, the output range would be:

```
0xffff ===> -1 
0x8000 ====> -32768
0x0000 ====> +1 LSB say 1 
0x7FFF ====> 32767 MAX
```

If you really want the range as you specified, do the following: (Keeping the msbyte and lsbyte `unsigned`)

```
int16_t num16=0;
temp = (msbyte<<8) | lsbyte;
num16 = (int16_t)(temp & 0x7FFF);  /* Get the number */
if(temp & 0x8000) { /* Get sign bit */
  num16 = num16 * -1 - 1;
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/PHaHNO)

Comment: the MIN should be -32768 = 0xffff

Comment: I am glad if it helps you. I hope you understood why did you need unsigned.

Comment: I've understood the unsigned but the I'm still trying with the rest

Comment: no need for cast before shifting? also he prints using wrong format specifier

Comment: @Giorgi You can see integral type promotion while shifting to understand why no cast is required. Correct way to print would be: `printf(" %4x temp %" PRId16 "\n", (unsigned int)temp, temp);`

Comment: @MohitJain: I thought shifting more than size of the object being shifted was not ok, e.g., 8 in this case

Comment: @Giorgi In C99 specs check section 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators > Semantics (Same in C11 also): "The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the **promoted** left operand, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
char msbyte =0x7f;
char lsbyte = 0xff;
```

to

```
unsigned char msbyte =0x7f;
unsigned char lsbyte = 0xff;
```

`char` is a signed type on your implementation and undergoes sign extension when promoted to `int`.

Also change:

```
printf(" %4x temp %d ", temp,temp);
```

to

```
printf(" %4x temp %d ", (uint16_t) temp,temp);
```

to avoid signed extension if `temp` is negative.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your problem is that the high bit is being used as a sign bit.

You can avoid this using:

```
uint8_t msbyte =0x7f;
uint8_t lsbyte = 0xff;
uint16_t temp=0;
```

Additionally, I find using the [AVR type defs](http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html), [Short tutorial](http://winavr.scienceprog.com/avr-gcc-tutorial/more-about-c-types-in-avr-gcc.html) useful while handling embedded/device data.

For instance define:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE
typedef unsigned int WORD
```

and use BYTE and WORD in your code.

Comment: I use the C99 standard header `<stdint.h>` for portable size-annotated primitive types, e.g. `uint8_t` and corresponding `UINT8_MAX` etc.